# Does having more items on my desktop affect my system's performance?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I've noticed how whenever I alt-tab out of a game that I run in a different resolution than my monitor (for instance, I run CS:GO in 720p while my monitor runs at 1080p) when I alt-tab, it kinda reloads and "resizes" my icons on my desktop to fit my screen. But I noticed how it went from a second to alt-tab, to 5 seconds and that started to happen when my desktop started filling up and sometimes explorer.exe stops working whenever I move some files to my desktop.

Does having all [those files](https://gyazo.com/31417bdb5839404fe09c20917e6b1a73) messing up my desktop? So should I clean up my desktop? or is this just a caching problem of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes most definitely.

Long answer: well, yes... most definitely. :D

Here's why. When you change resolution 2 factors will make it take longer:

1. Resolution change will put the monitor in a different state, so there's a bit of a delay before your monitor switched resolution, but windows doesn't really care about this.
2. It resizes your desktop, and thus the programs on it and the icons. Normally this is indeed a matter of seconds.

But because you have over 2000 icons there, it means windows has to access 2000+ small files. 2000+ small files takes quite a bit longer than one large file of the same size. It has to access every file, get its properties and move it around physically, even when off-screen.

You can easily counteract this by creating a folder on your desktop and move everything into it. If you save to desktop, you just have to go into one more folder, and when accessing from your desktop, you also just have to go into one folder.